# Sending standard output from command line function to python StringIO object

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, imagemagick

Wow, it was hard to encapsulate my issue here into a succinct headline. I hope I managed.

I've got a simple thumbnail feature that is causing me issues when I try to retrieve a URL from Amazon S3, then `convert` it using ImageMagick. I would normally use PIL to read in an image file and convert it, but PIL doesn't read in PDF formats, so I'm resorting to convert through a subprocess call.

Here's some code from a django views.py. The idea here is that I get a file url from S3, open it with `convert`, process it into a PNG, send it to stdout, and then use the outputted buffer to load up a StringIO object, which then gets passed back to default_storages to save the thumbnail file back to S3. Quite a faff for such a simple job, but there you go.

**Please note: I cannot reliably save a file to disk using `convert` on my production set-up with Heroku, otherwise, I'd be doing that already.**

```
def _large_thumbnail_s3(p):

    # get the URL from S3, trimming off the expiry info etc. So far so good.

    url = default_storage.url(p+'.pdf').split('?')
    url = url[0]

    # this opens the PDF file fine, and proceeds to convert and send 
    # the new PNG to the buffer via standard output.

    from subprocess import call 
    call("convert -thumbnail '400x600>' -density 96 -quality 85 "
        +url
        +" png:-", shell=True)

    from StringIO import StringIO

    # here's where the problem starts. I'm clearly not reading
    # in the stdout correctly, as I get a IOError: File not open for reading
    # from this next line of code:

    completeStdin = sys.stdout.read()
    im = StringIO(completeStdin)

    # now take the StringIO PNG object and save it back to S3 (this 
    # should not be an issue.

    im = default_storage.open(p+'_lg.png', 'w+b')
    im.close()
```

Can anyone tell me a) where I might be going wrong with regards sending the output back to the thumbnail function, and b) whether you can suggest any more robust alternatives to what seems a pretty hacky way of doing this!

TIA

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `subprocess.check_output`, not `subprocess.call`:

```python
from subprocess import check_output
from StringIO import StringIO

out, err = check_output("convert -thumbnail '400x600>' -density 96 -quality 85 "
    +url
    +" png:-", shell=True)

buffer = StringIO(out)
```

Comment: Very close! This resulted in a `ValueError: too many values to unpack` message; changing `out, err = check_output(...` to `out = check_output(...` fixed it. Thanks!